# Exclude account for AD listing

Tags: powershell

Heloo

I have this script to search for inactive users in AD. Is there someway to ad exclusion of accounts as i see service account and similar in the list? i do not care if i manually have to add each account before i run it if it's possible to do so.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
Get-ADUser -Filter {((Enabled -eq $true) -and (LastLogonDate -lt $date))} -Properties LastLogonDate | select samaccountname, Name, LastLogonDate | Sort-Object LastLogonDate | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Output\InactiveADUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: if you see service accounts in this list, then you have used user accounts used as service account and not real service accounts. Howerever, I prefer `Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.0:0:0 -UsersOnly | Where-Object Enabled` or `Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -DateTime $Date -UsersOnly | Where-Object Enabled` to retrieve inactive accounts. You can still replace the filter for the result with `Where-Object { $_.Enabled -and $excludes -notcontains $_.SamAccountName }` as @Theo answered you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Where-Object` clause to further filter on the accounts you do not want like below:

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90).Date

# create an array of SamAccountNames to exclude.
# if you have only one item, surround it with @() to force it as array
$excludes = 'jdoe', 'jbloggs'
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True' -and LastLogonDate -lt $date" -Properties LastLogonDate | 
    Where-Object { $excludes -notcontains $_.SamAccountName } |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, Name, LastLogonDate | 
    Sort-Object LastLogonDate | 
    Export-CSV -Path "C:\Output\InactiveADUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

<sup>P.S. `-Filter` should be a string, not a scriptblock and I have used `.Date` to set the date to compare against to midnight</sup>